# strip() function usage in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some script that is written in Python and in that script it is mentioned :

```
hostNumber = hostNumber.strip("0")
```

and when we are giving the `hostNumber` as `'c0001230'` it is removing all the zeros which is as per the script.
But we want it will remove starting zeros and return the last 4 digits of `hostNumber`.

Comment: Let me clarify your question. Will it always be the last 4 numbers? Or could it be the last 3 numbers as well? I would suggest providing a few more example cases with their desired outputs. You might leverage a regex if necessary.

Comment: Using `hostNumber[-4:]` will give you `1230`.

Comment: Have a look ar `rstrip` and `lstrip`

Comment: You don't have starting zeros; you have a bunch of zeros *after* an initial `c` (or maybe some other character or characters). You have to remove them before `strip` can remove the 0s. E.g. `hostNumber.lstrip('0c')`. (The order of the argument doesn't matter; `0c` and `c0` would both remove any number of `c`s and `0`s from the left side of the string.)

Comment: str.strip() will strip from both sides. Usually used for stripping whitespace. For this case, why not use something like `int(hostNumber[1:])` (assuming there's always exactly one leading non-digit character).

Answer (score 0):

The strip() function removes all leading and trailing characters. In this case:

```
hostnumber = "c0001230"
hostnumber = hostnumber.strip("0")
print(hostnumber)
"c000123"
```

Is the "c" character intended? Based on your question, the output you wanted was 0123, correct? The way I would recommend to approach this is:

```
hostnumber = "c0001230"
hostnumber = hostnumber.strip("0")
hostnumber = hostnumber[-4:]
print(hostnumber)
"0123"
```

If there are any other issues with this answer, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

To address your use of `strip()`, you will run into issues in your case where the string begins with a letter. You will likely be better off prescribing a specific pattern via a regular expression (regex). Here is a regex that should accomplish what you want, as well as some more example cases:

```
r'[1-9][0-9]+$'
```

This looks for a digit from 1-9 followed by one or more digits from 0-9 up until the end of the string (denoted by `$`).

```
import re

s = ['c0001230','f0000546','y0098061','h0064125','a0000030']

outputs = [re.findall(r'[1-9][0-9]+$', i)[0] for i in s]
```

Yields:

```
['1230', '546', '98061', '64125', '30']
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/SsZx0n/1/) to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module of python:

```
import re
hostNumber = str('c0001230')
hostNumr = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', hostNumber)
hostChar = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', hostNumber)
hostNumber = hostChar + str(int(hostNumr))
print(int(hostNumr), hostChar, hostNumber)
```

Of course you can remove several lines which are added for clarity.

The assumption is that you have hostNumber which consists of CHAR+INT. If you need to remove the trailing 0 (i.e. converting 1230 to 123, add the `strip` at the very end.